# How change fields read_only value based on other fields while creating new record?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to make some fields in Django admin `read_only` based on other fields value on creating and before save the record.

for example `cloths` model:
and it has `Boolean` field called `is_t_shirt` when the user start fill the form when he put this indicator `True` I want to make other fields such as `long_of_leg` read only and when that indicator `False` this field will be editable.

All of that before saving and when editing existing or creating new record, may I can called that as real time or run time.

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Django has a built in way to set a field as read only before saving. To achieve this you will have to add some custom JavaScript to add an event listener to the checkbox to see when it is checked/unchecked and then set the disabled attribute on the input fields you would like to disable.

Check out these links:

[Checkbox Check Event Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544104/checkbox-check-event-listener)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/javascript/