# trigger page reload on specific checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Ok, I have a code which saves 30 or so checkbox selections to local storage which works fine, I also have a separate checkbox (as below) which when checked automatically reloads the page

```
<input type="checkbox" id="autoload" class="autoload"> Tick this box to automatically update the results as you choose them from the options below
```

Below is the code I have to trigger the page reload

```
if ($('#autoload').is(':checked')) {
    location.reload(); 
    }
```

Below is the code which saves the checkboxes to local storage and where I want to add the trigger reload code above

```
window.onload = function() {
   function onClickBox() {
      var arr = $('.box').map(function() {
         return this.checked;
      }).get();
      localStorage.setItem("checked", JSON.stringify(arr));
   }
   $(document).ready(function() {
      var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checked')) || [];
      arr.forEach(function(checked, i) {
         $('.box').eq(i).prop('checked', checked);
      });
      $(".box").click(onClickBox);
   });
}
```

My problem is I do not know where or how to place the trigger page reload code into the code above to make it work. Hope all my babblings make sense, any help really appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544104/checkbox-check-event-listener
check this link I think this might work.

Comment: What is the realtion between `.box` checkboxes and `#autoload` checkbox?

Comment: .box are the classes to all the checkboxes, #autoload is the id for the checkbox which triggers the page reload

Answer (score 0):

You can use ".change" trigger for check box like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
   function onClickBox() {
      var arr = $('.box').map(function() {
         return this.checked;
      }).get();
      localStorage.setItem("checked", JSON.stringify(arr));
   }
   $(document).ready(function() {
      var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checked')) || [];
      arr.forEach(function(checked, i) {
         $('.box').eq(i).prop('checked', checked);
      });
      $(".box").click(onClickBox);
   });
}

$('#autoload').change(() => {
   if ($('#autoload').is(':checked')) {
      location.reload();
   }
});
```

Comment: I have tried what you suggested, but unfortunately, it does not seem to work :(

Comment: Anybody got any other thoughts on how I can sort it please?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it myself

```
window.onload = function() {
   function onClickBox() {
      var arr = $('.box').map(function() {
         return this.checked;
      }).get();
      localStorage.setItem("checked", JSON.stringify(arr));
      if ($('#autoload').is(':checked')) {
         location.reload()
      };
   }
   $(document).ready(function() {
      var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checked')) || [];
      arr.forEach(function(checked, i) {
         $('.box').eq(i).prop('checked', checked);
      });
      $(".box").click(onClickBox);
   });
}
```